# Java class error in my script

Tags: java

I have made a lot of research at internet. I can not find a solution to the error at my Java

[image]

Comment: Please include your code directly in the question and provide a proper problem description. **Linking** to an **image** is almost the worst you can do. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`double` is only used for variable declaration or parameter typing. Just use `x`. (Also, please don't post images of code, paste the real code here in your question.)

Comment: Thank you so much ! It's working now :)

Comment: I'm glad it's working. To avoid future downvotes on your questions, I suggest reading the FAQs and help center :) Good luck

Comment: I'm new on this page so I don't know how it works, but I will read it thanks! Can I ask you another question? Do you maybe know how to type the sin^2 function in java ?

Comment: You would benefit greatly from [googling these questions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20sine%20function) :)

Comment: google dindnt knew! :-) but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

double sum = Math.sin(x) + Math.cos(x);